# Transfer an Applet to a new div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, applet

I want to transfer an applet from one div to another using jQuery or JavaScript. Consider the following HTML

```
<button type="button" onclick="transfer()">Transfer Now</button>
<div id="initializedAppletDiv">
    <applet id="initializedApplet" code="my.code.JNLPAppletLauncher">
        <param name="the parameters, etc." />
    </applet>
</div>
<div id="transferAppletDiv">
    <applet id="transferApplet"></applet>
</div>
```

Clicking on the button would then transfer the applet using something along the following

```
// Pseudo code -- does not work!
function transfer() {
    var appletInstance = $('#initialziedApplet');
    $('#transferApplet').applet = appletInstance;
}
```

Is what I'm proposing possible? If so, how would I do it? I want to avoid reloading the applet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use detach.

http://api.jquery.com/detach/

```
$('#transferAppletDiv').html($('#initializedApplet').detach());
```

That way you move the element and keep all of the DOM attributes with it.